# AngularJS Popover w/ Template Doesn't Show

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a UI Bootstrap popover in AngularJS that works fine in my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ek1ypze/pen/dopKpK), but when I try to transfer it to my work it doesn't show up at all. When trying out the popovers from the [UI Bootstrap Demos](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), the Dynamic Popover DOES work. The only issue I'm getting is with the Popover w/ Template.

As this is part of a larger code, ng-app and controller are declared elsewhere.

Here is my code:

**top.html**

```
<div class="top_bar">
    <div class="logo">
        <a ui-sref="main.chat">
            <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- START Popover -->
    <a class="user-settings" popover-placement="bottom" popover-template="user-menu.html" popover-trigger="click">
        <span class="user-name">{{sidebarController.get_name()}}</span>
        <img src="images/avatar.png" />

        <script id="user-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <p><a href="#">{{ edit_profile }}</a></p>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Logout</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Admin Panel</button>
        </script>


    </a>
    <!-- END Popover -->
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module(
    'bst.topbar',
    [
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'bst.uirouter'
    ]
);

}());
```

**controller.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Controller for topbar
     */
    var topbar_controller = function(
        $state,
        topbarService,
        sidebarService,
        sidebarStorer,
        profileStorer
    ) {
        this.$state = $state;
        this.currentUserId = sidebarService.currentUserId;
        this.get_name = sidebarService.get_name.bind(this);
        this.vCardStorage = profileStorer.get_storage();
        this.set_tab = sidebarStorer.set_current_tab;

        $state.edit_profile = 'Edit Profile';
    };

    angular.module('bst.topbar').controller(
        'bst.topbar.Controller', [
            '$state',
            'bst.topbar.Service',
            'bst.sidebar.Service',
            'bst.sidebar.Storer',
            'bst.profile.info.Storer',
            topbar_controller
        ]
    );

}());
```

Comment: I've hit limitations with angular's popover, so I ended up making my own directive. You might find it useful: https://github.com/softwaredoug/inspector-gadget

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Also popover with template is new to UI Bootstrap 0.13.0.  This version is also dependent upon AngularJS 1.3+  and Bootstrap 3+?  Have you made sure that you have all of the correct versions loaded in your local file?

Answer (score 4):

popover-template takes expression as parameter. try add quotes

```
popover-template="'user-menu.html'"
```

Comment: this is true if we use "uib-popover-template" instead of "popover-template" :)